# Regex to match numbers from large document in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to create a regex that could match numbers from large document.

Find at least 10 continuous digits (which can go to maximum 15 digits) that could be separated by one or multiple

```
-
_
\s
(
)
[
]
```

**Tried-**

```
/(?:((\d([ \-_\s]+?)){5,8}))/
```

Eg:

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-12-34
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
123-456-789-0
123---456---789---987
12 34 56 78 90
12_ -34_-56--78__90
```

Comment: `' -_'` creates a range inside a character class. Try `/\d(?:[-\][()_\s]*\d){9,14}/g`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lUdJE1/1).

Comment: `(?:\d[-_\s()\]\[]*){10,15}` should work for you.

Comment: @anubhava This also matches 10 white spaces

Comment: @Letmesee: Are you sure? This regex has non-optional `\d` so it cannot match spaces with digits.

Comment: it may contains 10 to 15 digits and can contains illimited specials characters in this 10-15 digits ?

Comment: The "problem" with `(?:\d[-_\s()\]\[]*){10,15}` is that the matches will contain trailing non-digit symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/\d(?:[-_\][()\s]*\d){9,14}/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lUdJE1/1)

**Details**

- `\d` - a digit
- `(?:[-_\][()\s]*\d){9,14}` - 9 to 14 repetitions of

  - `[-_\][()\s]*` - 0 or more repetitions of `-`, `_`, `]`, `[`, `(`, `)` or whitespace
  - `\d` - a digit.

Note you do not need to escape `[` inside a character class, it is parsed as a literal `[` in a JS regex. However, `]` must be escaped there, otherwise, it will close the character class prematurely.